# expo local notifications how to set custom start and custom repeat

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm creating an app in react native using expo where I need to set both a custom start time and a custom repeat interval time for notifications based on user input. For example, I need to start notifications in 15 days and then repeat every 27 days thereafter. I can figure out how to get it to trigger in 15 days, or repeat every 27 days, but not both together. I need it to work on Android and iOS.

```
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";

export default function notificationsConfig(repeatLength) {
  const config = {
    content: {
      title: "Reminder",
      body: "body.",
      sound: false,
      priority: Notifications.AndroidNotificationPriority.HIGH,
      color: "blue",
    },
    trigger: {
/****Is there a way to set first notification date here?******/
      seconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * repeatLength,
      repeats: true,
    },
  };

  return config;
}
```

Thank you!